# How to run django project again on 127.0.0.1:8000? no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I haven't ran project for long time, so there possibly happened some kind of conflict.

When I am trying to run the django + postgresql localhost  server by `python manage.py runserver` get this in response:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.17.0.1", user "thekotik", database "fuck3", SSL off
```

Normally it should run on 127.0.0.1:8000, but it seems that because of different project that ran on 127.0.0.1:5000 of because of installing docker, it's now somehow broken.

So how to fix this error? How to run it again on 127.0.0.1:8000?

EDIT: In `pg_hba.conf` :

```
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        172.17.0.1              trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: check pg_hba.conf file and check postgres server ip. I think it has change the `host  172.17.0.1` to something else.

Comment: @RahulKP running server = error. see the question

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare please check edited question

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare why is it running at all on 172.17.0.1  when it shouldn't

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare tried, result is the same 'no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.17.0.1", user "thekotik", database "closerdb", SSL off'

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

Add or edit the following line in your postgresql.conf :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Add the following line as the first line of pg_hba.conf. It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Comment: edited files, but didn't help. possibly not applied, because postgres has to be restarted to apply changes, but can't figure out how.

Comment: @Vinand refer this `https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/server-start.html`

Comment: @PiushS.Wanare successfully restarted server, but error remains

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and I solved it by changing IPv4 local connections in pg_hba.file to

```
host    all             all             all            trust
```

and it solved the problem